# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection does not contain a definition for 'AddWithvalue'

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand

```
    public static DataTable SqlDataTable(string sql, IDictionary<string, object> values)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            foreach (var item in values)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithvalue("@" + item.Key, item.Value);  // error
            }
          .......
          ........
```

> Error 4   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection' does not
>   contain a definition for 'AddWithvalue' and no extension method
>   'AddWithvalue' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Why I get this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C#` is a `case-sensitive` language.The method you are trying to call is [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with capital `V` not `AddWithvalue`.